# Building a Markdown parser. Is it possible to detect links without detecting underscores in them?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a basic Markdown parser, and I want to build a regular expression that can detect links and emphasis.

In Markdown links look like `[text](URL)` and emphasis/italics look like `*text*` or `_text_`.

I have no problem detecting emphasis, nor do I have issue detecting links, but when links have underscores in them, such as `http://example.com/link_to_article`, my parser detects `_to_` as an attempt at emphasis.

How do I stop this?

My first attempt was to make sure there were no characters before the first underscore or after the second, but inline emphasis is totally valid, as seen here on Stac*koverfl*ow so examples like `intere_stin_g` are totally valid, shooting that idea in the foot.

So how would I accomplish this?

Comment: Unless until you suggest some rule to distinguish between `link_to_article` (non-emphasis) and `intere_stin_g` (emphasis) it won't be possible to avoid this.

Comment: Just detect links first and don't look for emphasis within text already classified as a URL.

Comment: Inline emphasis with asterisks is valid, but I think Stack Overflow uses a variant of Markdown which does not recognize inter_word_emphasis_with_underscores.

Comment: @DougSmith: I’m looking in the original posts and you used asterisks. As my comment stated, asterisks indeed have interword emphasis, but in Stack Overflow’s variant of Markdown, *underscores don’t*.

Comment: @icktoofay Oh interesting, good call.

Answer (score 3):

There are three main ways to do this.

1. A big, fancy regex, which'll look something like this:

   ```
   (?<!\(\s*\S+)_([^_]+)_(?!\S+(?:\s+"[^"]")\s*\))
   ```

   I *strongly* recommend against this approach, because even that monstrosity isn't fully standard-compliant, and... I mean, who wants to try to decipher that? Even splitting it over multiple lines only makes it a little better. Also, that lookbehind might not even be accepted, depending on your regex engine.
2. Disallow mid-word italics using `_`. This makes your regex a whole lot simpler:

   ```
   \b_[^_]+_\b
   ```

   Stack Overflow does this.
3. Orient your entire program around a stream-based design, where you match fragments and parse them as you work through the string. This is a bit harder to code, but would basically be:

   1. Find the first thing that looks like italics
   2. Find the first thing that looks like a link
   3. Format it based on which one matches earlier.

NB: I put `[^_]` in a few places when that's not *strictly* accurate; more accurate would be `(?:(?<!\\)(\\\\)*\\_|[^_])+`; i.e. a series of escaped `_` or non-`_` characters. Alternatively, you could do something roughly like `_.*?(?<!\\)(\\\\)*_`; i.e. match from `_` until the very next unescaped `_`.

---

P.S. If you want to learn more about regex, there are a lot of handy tools to help you, like [online parsers](https://regex101.com/) and [tutorials](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)